# IUSR not able to access network resources

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a website which access a network path for images including logos on the website. There is a virtual directory pointing to this network shared folder and I gave anonymous access to this virtual directory. This is to make sure that logos and images are available in login page, register page.

Webserver is running windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5
Fileserver is running windows 2008 R2
Both are on same domain network

I use IUSR as anonymous user identity, and this works fine in UAT environment. Unfortunately not working on production environment. While troubleshooting I grant Everyone full access to network shared folder, still no luck. The images are not loading for anonymous users.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the app pool running as? Assuming it's the default of `AppPoolIdentity`, the worker process *should* be authenticating across the network as the machine's domain account (i.e. `MACHINENAME$`)

Assuming that your sharing and NTFS permissions are set up to allow access from this account, then you may find that actually the worker process is trying to authenticate as `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS`

I've come across this very issue on production systems (and it would appear, [so have others](http://forums.iis.net/t/1181039.aspx)). The AppPool would [randomly stop authenticating](http://forums.iis.net/post/2011028.aspx) as the domain computer and start trying to authenticate anonymously, and only a reboot of the server would fix it. In the end, we changed our AppPools to run under the `NetworkService` account and they have been stable ever since.

Comment: The analysis is great, but doesn't seem to contain a recommendation to resolve the issue. Usually the application identity should be set as a domain service account, and then permissions (file share, database and so on) can be granted to that service account.